# Custom Sheet Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, xib

Working on an older project that uses xib in Xcode 8. Code is in single AppDelegate class with single MainMenu.xib. A custom window can be shown as a sheet by double clicking a table row or by a button from another window as a window. Custom window displays information and does not need completionHandler.
An alert sheet is also attached to same window as custom sheet can show on.
My issue is if I view the custom sheet, when the alert shows, dismissing the alert will activate the custom sheet to show then. I tried to order out custom sheet with release when closed checked in IB. What I'm I not doing right here. Code in AppDelegate that deals with sheets below:

```
    -(void)doubleClickTableRow:(id)nid
{
    [self.window beginSheet:self.descriptionWindow completionHandler:nil];
}

-(IBAction)closeWorkDescription:(id)sender;
{
    [self.descriptionWindow orderOut:self];

}


-(IBAction)showWorkDescription:(id)sender;
{
    [self.descriptionWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [self.descriptionWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
}

-(void) returnSeconds
{
NSAlert *alertSheet = [[NSAlert alloc]init];
            [alertSheet setMessageText:@“The alert Title.”];
            [alertSheet setInformativeText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“The alert message.”, self.projectNumber,self.projectName]];
            [alertSheet beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: Close the custom sheet before showing the alert?

Comment: I am closing custom sheet with closeWorkDescription: and have released when close checked in IB. When I close the alert sheet the alert sheet closes but immediately custom sheet opens for some reason. What's making the custom sheet open?

Comment: `closeWorkDescription` doesn't end the sheet. Is the custom sheet open when you call `[alertSheet beginSheetModalForWindow:…]`?

Comment: How do I properly end my custom sheet? Custom sheet is visibly not showing when alert sheet is called. I've tried     [NSApp endSheet:self.descriptionWindow];
    [self.descriptionWindow orderOut:self];
    [self.descriptionWindow close];

Comment: Make sure you don't use `descriptionWindow` as window and sheet at the same time.